# Amazon Athena same query some times fails with HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a large number of log files containing lines of JSON object stored in Amazon S3. This files are compressed using LZO.

The format is using Hive partition like below

```
s3://bucket/logs/year=2017/month=01/day=01/log00_00.txt.lzo
```

The table definition is like below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
    attr1 string,
    attr2 string,
    attr3 string,
)
PARTITIONED BY (
    year string,
    month string,
    day string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://bucket/logs/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

When I tried executing query for a month like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE year = '2017' AND month = '05';
```

the query always fails

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: 
Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): expected a valid value
(number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at
[Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@381dc2b6; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I tried querying for smaller number of data, i.e. in a day like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE year = '2017' AND month = '05' AND day = '01'
```

This query some times fails with error like above, although the probability of success is very high.

So now when I have to query for a month, I have to iterate for every day in the month and then rerun the execution for the failed day.

Is there something that I can do to fix that? Or is this a bug from AWS Athena?

Answer (score 0):

It might mean that one of the results has an unexpected character or value. Could be a parsing error or improperly formatted JSON in the row.

I would probably try selecting a chunk of the data with no constraints that corresponds to the date selection that is failing. (`select * from logs limit 10000;`, for example) and manually validate that I get the expected results for the year month and day every time.

A manual way of validating would be to pull the query results into a Linux/mac box and do something like `cat log | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | uniq -c` assuming that your first column is year and second is month (and they are space delimited). This will give you all the unique values for the first two and you might notice some strange values.

If re-running the same Athena query on the same day intermittently fails then, open a support ticket with AWS or switch to a regex pattern and try to collect some examples of data that causes it to fail.